# simple example of monad that takes integers

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I am writing a Monad that composes functions, f and g, based on this explanation of Monads (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhuHCtR3xq8). the explanation stops at a crucial part: to compose a function (say f) `a -> ma` with another (say g) `a -> ma`, you need a way to convert `ma` to `a`, to take stuff out of the monad container (otherwise how could you feed the output of f into g??) and that is not addressed.

assume we have f and g that map an Integer and return a Maybe:

```
f :: Int -> Maybe Int
f = \x -> (Just x)

g :: Int -> Maybe Int
g = \x -> (Just x)
```

I want to make a Monad that allows me to compose f and g, so that `(g o f)(x)` (meaning `f(g(x))`) can be evaluated. for this to work we need a way to convert `Maybe Int` (the output of f) into `Int` so it can be sent to g. when the `Maybe` container has a value in it, we just pull out the value. when g's output is Nothing, we can consider the value 0 (I know g's output can't be Nothing the g above but lets assume it could for another f).

this is my failed attempt to define a Monad MyMonad that does this:

```
f :: Int -> Maybe Int
f = \x -> (Just x)

g :: Int -> Maybe Int
g = \x -> (Just x)

data MyMonad a = Maybe a

instance Monad MyMonad where
  return x = MyMonad x
  Just x >>= (\x -> MyMonad (Just x))
  Nothing >>= (\x -> MyMonad (Just 0))
```

can someone clarify what is wrong here? from tutorials it's very hard to know what the right way to pattern match inside functions is (to handle case of Just vs. Nothing here) and to tease apart all the different syntaxes of instantiating a Monad. this example doesn't help (https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads#Maybe_a_monad): after introducing bind `>>=` the sheep example doesn't even use it and uses a combinator instead.

Comment: In order to be a `Monad`, the type needs to be a type constructor like `data MyMonad a = Maybe a`. Currently, your type has kind `*`, so it can't be made into a monad.

Comment: @4castle: thanks fixed it but there's something more fundamental wrong with my syntax and i am not sure what

Comment: `comb` in your second link *is* bind.

Comment: You haven't defined `Just` or `Nothing` as data constructors for `MyMonad`. Also, you're missing an `=` sign and a function variable in the definition for `>>=`. You can't pattern match on functions.

Comment: @4castle: can you say more about ``>>=`` use in this case? why do i need an equal sign? can't i define theoretically all my functions as lamdas and never use an equal sign?

Comment: The `=` sign is required in order to define a value for a name. Your code already uses one when you defined `f` as `f = ...`. Similarly, you could do `(>>=) = \x f -> ...`, but it's a bit easier to read if you define `>>=` in infix form.

Comment: I might also add that defining a "monad that takes integers" is an impossibility, because a monad needs to be able to "hold" any type of value. That's why `>>=` is generalized to `a` instead of just `Int` in its definition: `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`

Comment: @4castle: based on ``(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`` if i use infix notation can't i write: ``m a >>= f``, where ``f`` is a function that takes an ``a`` and returns an ``m b``?

Comment: @4castle: thanks for clarifying the generality of times. if you have an example of how to correctly write this simple operation that would help. i'm just trying to correctly stick and unstick stuff in a monad but the syntax and all the different ways of writing it is hopelessly confusing.

Answer (score 5):

When you first start learning monads, the easiest one to learn is called the `Identity` monad. It looks like this is what you're actually trying to implement, but you're getting the word `Maybe` stuck in there somewhere, and it's throwing everything off. (That, or you actually are trying to implement the `Maybe` monad, but you've not defined `Just` or `Nothing` anywhere.)

If `MyMonad` is like the `Identity` monad, the correct definition would be:

```
f :: Int -> MyMonad Int
f = \x -> MyIdentity x

g :: Int -> MyMonad Int
g = \x -> MyIdentity x

data MyMonad a = MyIdentity a

instance Monad MyMonad where
    return x = MyIdentity x     -- return = \x -> MyIdentity x
    (MyIdentity x) >>= f = f x  -- (>>=) = \(MyIdentity x) f -> f x
```

If `MyMonad` is like the `Maybe` monad, the correct definition would be:

```
f :: Int -> MyMonad Int
f = \x -> MyJust x

g :: Int -> MyMonad Int
g = \x -> MyJust x

data MyMonad a = MyNothing | MyJust a

instance Monad MyMonad where
    return x = MyJust x
    (MyJust x) >>= f = f x
    MyNothing  >>= f = MyNothing
```

(Note, for these to compile, you need to also define an instance for `Functor` and `Applicative`.)

P.S. To define `>>=` for the `Maybe` monad using lambda notation, you'll need a `case` expression:

```
(>>=) = \m f -> case m of
    MyJust x  -> f x
    MyNothing -> MyNothing
```

Comment: And in particular note that there is no function of type `MyMonad a -> a` defined anywhere in either of these. @user8379674 asserts several times that this is needed, but it simply isn't -- and indeed for the second definition of `MyMonad`, it's not *possible* to define a sensible function with that type!

Comment: @DanielWagner: can you explain why it's not needed rather than just asserting it? if a monad is a way to take two processes with signature (a->ma) and compose them then how can you do this *without* ever taking the output of the process evaluated first and making it compatible with the distinct input type of the process evaluated second? unless you disagree with that characterization

Comment: @user8379674 I'm not sure I can explain *why* it's not needed, but I can provide some evidence that this is a bad way of thinking about the problem. To start with: if there isn't a function of type `MyMonad a -> a` in the above code, and you agree that the above code fully implements a monad for `MyMonad`, then this should be 100% convincing evidence that a it isn't necessary to define a function of type `MyMonad a -> a` in the process of implementing a monad. To take another tack: you seem to be thinking of `m a` as "containing" an `a`. (cont'd)

Comment: @4castle: could you show how the ``f = f x`` notation after bind would look like in full lambda notation?

Comment: @user8379674 But this isn't necessarily true. In fact, for some sensible monads `m`, an `m a` doesn't have an `a` inside at all, and so `m a -> a` doesn't make sense; or may "contain" *many* values of type `a`. In these situations, it need not be sensible to write a function of type `m a -> a`, which would necessarily exalt one of these values above the others -- all values may be useful. In still other situations, values of type `m a` only latently "contain" an `a`. (cont'd)

Comment: @user8379674 For example, the state monad can be thought of as "containing" a single `a`, but only after performing some computation on an unrelated type `s`. So it isn't sensible to demand a function of type `State s a -> a`, because we must have an `s` to compute with before we can produce an `a`. Nevertheless, in all the situations I've mentioned so far, it is possible to turn an `a -> m b` into an `m a -> m b` without first turning it into an `a -> b`; and in some sense, the possibility of doing this is the entire point of the monad abstraction.

Comment: @user8379674 ...and, as a higher-level comment: though I could continue at length, I think speaking abstractly about monads at this point is a bit optimistic. You will get a much better intuition for what monads are about by implementing and using several different monads -- by getting specific and talking about concrete monads -- than you will by thinking about and discussing monads in their full generality.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the fish (`>=>`) operator (i'd seen it was called fish at some places but nothing serious about the name). If i am not mistaken you want to compose two functions each taking a binary value to return a monadic value. So let's find the type of our compositing function

```
(a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> mc)
```

which happens to be [`>=>` in `Control.Monad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-).

so

```
f :: Int -> Maybe Int
f = \x -> (Just x)

g :: Int -> Maybe Int
g = \x -> (Just x)

f >=> g $ 10
Just 10
```

or

```
f :: Int -> [Int]
f = \x -> replicate x x

g :: Int -> [Maybe Int]
g = \x -> [Just x]
f >=> g $ 10
[Just 10,Just 10,Just 10,Just 10,Just 10,Just 10,Just 10,Just 10,Just 10,Just 10]
```

You also have another fish `<=<` swimming to left which is the flipped version of `>=>`.

Comment: can you explain the line ``f >=> g $ 10``? it's just ``(>=>) f g 10`` it seems. what if ``f`` returned a ``Nothing``? then you couldn't pass it to ``g``

Comment: if we had ``f :: Int -> Maybe Int; f = \x -> if x > 5 then (Just x) else Nothing`` then ``(>=>) f g 3`` works it turns ``Nothing`` but it's like magic. shouldn't it give a type error because ``f`` returns ``Nothing`` and that gets passed to ``g`` which needs an ``Int``?

Comment: @user8379674 As per your second comment there is nothing magic. If you check the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.html#%3E%3D%3E) you will notice that `>=>` is in fact defined as `f >=> g = \x -> f x >>= g`. So obviously from the Monad typeclass instance of the `Maybe` type defines `>>=` as `Nothing >>= _ = Nothing` as far as i remember.